# Why JAXB inheritance not working in static class

Tags: java, binding, jaxb

I have xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="AppService1ResponseType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="AppResponseType">
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                <xs:element name="Person" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Element1" type="xs:string" nillable="true"
                                minOccurs="0" /> ....
```

which generate static class inside `AppService1ResponseType`

```
public static class Osoba
    implements Serializable
```

and `binding.xml`:

```
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='AppService1ResponseType']/xs:complexContent/xs:extension/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='Person']">
        <inheritance:implements>com.app.PersonI</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

which should implement interface to this generated class. I also tried another XPath or just `element[@name='Person']` but with no success. When I tried another non static class like AppService1ResponseType then inheritace works OK. Is there some workaround how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]: a complete complex type definition as well as binding.

Comment: Also what exactly is "no success"? Any error reports?

Comment: Disclaimer: I am the author of the JAXB Inheritance Plugin in question.

Comment: thx for the help. I found in another thread that I have wrong xPath so after I add /xs:complexType  it starts working. I am just not sure why this is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

ok. I found there was error in xpath which should end with `/xs:complexType`

so the correct xpath in binding is:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='AppService1ResponseType']/xs:complexContent/xs:extension/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='Person']/xs:complexType">
    <inheritance:implements>com.app.PersonI</inheritance:implements>
</jaxb:bindings>
```